# PSA: Review queue jumped in size

Tags: discussion

This is due to a change in the reputation limit for entering the queue:

[Can we raise the bar for reputation for late answers to bypass the review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-enter-the-review-queue)

Comment: I've been out of town for a few weeks and not doing much on here, so there's been one less regular-reviewer active. Just cleared my queue.